# Flyto error: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Trying to add a button that when pressed it moves the map to new York city. But whenever I try and use the button I get the error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons

I understand that I need to put the hook of flyto into a function as it's a hook but how would you do that combined with a class component.

Code:

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
       this.onClickNewYork = this.onClickNewYork.bind(this)
      }
      onClickNewYork() {
        const { map } = useLeaflet();
        map.flyTo([40.730610, -73.935242], 15)
      }
    return (
        <>
        <Button onPress={this.onClickNewYork}>
        <Map center={position} zoom={0}>
         
          <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
         </map>
        </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Which version of react-leaflet are you using?

Comment: @ghybs react-leaflet v2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it like this in react-leaflet version 2.x. Moreover you cannot use hooks inside class based components.

Normally to take the map reference you would use **withLeaflet HOC** but this is available only in components placed as Map child components.

What you should do here instead is take a map reference using a `ref` and then use it to call `map.fly()`

```
mapRef = React.createRef();

onClickNewYork() {
    this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo([40.73061, -73.935242], 15);
}

<Map
   center={position}
   zoom={0}
   style={{ height: "90vh" }}
   ref={this.mapRef}
 >
...
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flyto-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-component-o01v4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: the answer worked amazing but I'm now trying to feed the position through a variable but every time I pass any variable into onClickNewYork() the variable becomes undefined?

Comment: Please ask this in a separate thread and I will try to help. Make sure you provide all the necessary info/code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069831/cannot-read-property-lat-of-undefined-and-undefined

Comment: refs deprecated!

Comment: Not for react-leaflet v.2.x!