# Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined and undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm now trying to feed the position of the user through the variable `(coords)` but every time I pass any variable into onClickUserLoc() the variable has the error

> Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

and when I console.log it states undefined? The coords variable holds an array of location data such as lng and lat but become undefined in onClickUserLoc().

Code:

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
               ready: false,
               where: { lat: '', lng: '' },
               error: null,
               };
           this.onClickUserLoc = this.onClickUserLoc.bind(this)
          }
          
    componentDidMount() {
    let geoOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeOut: 20000,
      maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
    };
    this.setState({ ready: false, error: null });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      this.geoSuccess,
      this.geoFailure,
      geoOptions
    );
  }

  mapRef = React.createRef();

  

  geoSuccess = (position) => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    console.log(position.coords.longitude);
    console.log(this.state.where?.lng);
    console.log(this.state.where?.lat);
    

    this.setState({
      ready: true,
      where: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude 
      },
      
    });
    console.log(this.state.where?.lng);
    console.log(this.state.where?.lat);
  };
  geoFailure = (err) => {
    this.setState({ error: err.message });
    console.log(this.state.error);
  };

  

          onClickUserLoc({ coords }) {
            this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo(coords, 15);
            console.log(coords);
          }

         
render() {

const coords = [this.state.where?.lat, this.state.where?.lng];
        return (
            <>
            <Button onPress={this.onClickUserLoc}>
            <Map 
             center={[...]} 
             zoom={0}> 
             style={{ height: "90vh" }}
             ref={this.mapRef}
             
              <TileLayer
                  attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                  url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
             </map>
            </>
      )
    }
```

Comment: where does your `coords` variable coming from? Where is it defined? You need to pass it as an argument to `onClickUserLoc` if it not defined before invoking it

Comment: I'm creating the const  (coords) that combines the user's lat and long data from this.state inside the render. Is the problem that render is after OnClickUserLoc and the const (coords) only affect things inside the render such as the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to fly to the position you are right now (geolocation). Variable `coords` variable is defined inside render method. You either pass the coords variable as an argument to button's onPress :

```
 <Button onPress={() => this.onClickUserLoc(coords)}></Button>
```

but you don't need to destructure it here

```
onClickUserLoc(coords) { // here no need to destructure it.
   this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo(coords, 15);
}
```

or use the state variable `where` directly inside `onClickUserLoc` without passing any argument:

```
 onClickUserLoc() {
    const {
      where: { lat, lng }
    } = this.state;
    this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo([lat, lng], 15);
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-read-property-lat-of-undefined-and-undefined-in-react-leaflet-v2x-0xllv?file=/src/App.js:1242-1385)